# MSSQL connection using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

Iam so fresh with PHP so this problem so big to me. I dont know why and where my mistake is. Based on my research to connect to MSSQL database by using this code:

```
<?php
$run = mssql_connect('dev-svr05','sa','P@55w0rd', 'orlig_sm_dev');
if ($run)
{
    echo "Connection OK";
}
else
{
    echo "Connection Failed";
}
?>
```

But when i run this code i got this error message:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\phpscript\save_mssql.php on line 5
```

I using the same code to connect to MYSQL and its success but not with MSSQL. Can anybody please tell me why this is happen? Thank You

Comment: I guess you have not installed `PECL odbtp >= 1.1.1`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please guide how to install PECL odbtp >= 1.1.1

Comment: read [this](http://odbtp.sourceforge.net/install.html) page.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you [download the sql server binaries](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) from windows and use PDO.

```
try { 
        //In some occasions you only need to define IP/Hostname and you can forgo the \SQLEXPRESS part
        $db = new PDO( "sqlsrv:Server=HOSTNAME\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DATABASENAME","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
       $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
       // set this to your primary database
      $db->query("USE DATABASENAME");
    }

    catch( PDOException $e ) { 

       die( "Error connecting to SQL Server".$e ); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fourth parameter is expecting a true/false. Refer the below link and try:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

Try "sqlsrv_connect" instead of "mssql_connect"

Comment: Tried it. same error. PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\phpscript\save_mssql.php on line 14