# How do i connect to MSSQL database from php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, iis

I have a Windows Azure Server and I want to connect to MSSQL server from a PHP application. But when i try to connect to the database it pops an error message saying...

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'. ) )
```

I used this code to connect to the database..

```
<?php
    $serverName = "AZR-SRV-MAP01"; //serverName\instanceName

    // Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
    // The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"EmpSys");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
        echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
        echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
?>
```

I'm accessing the database using Windows Authentication, therefore I'm not specifying the `UID` and `PWD` parameters.

Please assist me to connect to the SQL server.

Comment: Try to add `"Trusted connection"=>"true"` to `$connectionInfo` array

Comment: `$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"EmpSys","Trusted connection"=>"true");`

@gofr1 you mean like this right? after adding it, the error got reduced and got the following error...

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -1 [code] => -1 [2] => Invalid option Trusted connection was passed to sqlsrv_connect. [message] => Invalid option Trusted connection was passed to sqlsrv_connect. ) ) `

Comment: Sorry, forgot that sqlsrv_connect uses trusted connection by default :( what are you running Apache, IIS?

Comment: I am using IIS - @gofr1

Comment: What authentication is set in IIS settings? Try to turn windows auth on. Also I suggest to add IIS tag and remove Windiws tag.

Comment: do you mean the 'authentication feature' on IIS

Comment: AFAIR yes, that's it. It seems you have Anonymous auth on, Windows auth off.

Comment: Now i enabled Windows Authentication but no luck. Do i have to turn off the Anonymous Authentication??

Comment: Check what user now is in error message? Yes, turn it off. PHP is trying to connect under the user which run the process, turning windows auth on and anonymous off should fix your issue.

Comment: I once install IIS and had the same issue, I wrote you what used to help me... But it was long time ago so I might forgot some details :/

Comment: Thanks man! it worked I turned on  Windows Authentication and Turned off Anonymous Authentication.. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah! That's great! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this already published answer about this topic. It seems that can help you.

[MSSQL connection using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29623841/6366593)

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

The working code to connect to the MSSQL database from PHP (thanks to  gofr1)..

```
<?php
    $serverName = "server_name"; //serverName\instanceName

    // Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
    // The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"db_name");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
        echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
        echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
?>
```

**EDIT**

You need to turn Windows Authentication On, and set Anonymous Authentication Off in IIS settings. To authorize to SQL Server by your local/domain account.